# Detecting number of objects in image Cloud Vision

Tags: image-recognition, vision, google-cloud-vision

I am sorry if this has been asked before but is there any way to count the number of a specific "tag" in an image using Cloud Vision? For instance, if I have a picture of a cat and a dog, can I make a request that will return "1 cat, 1 dog, 2 mammals" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Google Cloud Vision can't do that and you probably should look at services from MS and AWS, but... you could recursively split image into parts, like if you split it in three, the left one can say "cat", the right one "dog" and the middle says nothing useful -- that would with some probability mean that it's a 1 cat and 1 dog.

Comment: Ok, that’s what I was thinking. Thank you.